# How would I dynamically animate a row of elements to slide?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a row of 5 elements currently being displayed on my page, each of which contain images. The goal is when one of them is clicked it slides over to the left and displays information about it, while the other 4 fade out. When the element is clicked again it will slide back over to the right and the other images will fade back in. Currently I'm just trying to get the sliding to work, but I'm not understanding how to get the image to get to the right position after moving.

Currently for each element I have the style set to something like:

```
    @keyframes move {
        from {
            left: 0;
        }
        to {
            left: -100px;
        }
    }

    div.image{
        position: relative;
        display: block;
    }
```

Then in a separate JS function I have it set as

```
document.querySelector(".image").style.animation = "move 1s";
document.querySelector(".image").style.left = "-100px";
```

So this will obviously hard-code every image to move over roughly 100px, but for some icons further down the row 100px will obviously not be far enough. Is there any way to make this distance more dynamic?

Comment: This question is unclear. Be sure to include a minimal piece of code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using css transitions? You can do something like this:

```
#yourID {
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

Then you can set up your onclick event in your JS

```
var element = document.getElementById('yourID');
element.onclick = function(){
  element.style.left = '10%';
}
```

You could then set up a flag to toggle between left and right like this:

```
var toggled = false;
var element = document.getElementById('yourID');
element.onclick = function(){
  if(toggled === false)
  {
    element.style.left = '10%';
  } else {
    //return to original position
    element.style.(however you choose to style) = yourDefaultPosition;
  }
}
```